# Android activity launch from search

Tags: android

My Activities:

A - Main Activity (Kind of a login screen), finish() on going to any other activity

B - User Content

C = Other user content

When I go A > B > C, press home, launch app from launcher, I see C with the back stack restored B > C (top) , no problem here

When I go A > B > C, press home, launch app from google search bar on home screen, I see A, with Back Stack B > C > A (top).

Question is why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

Snippet from Manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name="ActivityA"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:launchMode="standard"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity 
    android:name="ActivityB"
    android:label="@string/b_screen_title" >
  </activity>
  <activity
    android:name="ActivityC"
    android:label="@string/c_screen_title"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
  </activity>
```

Comment: is the google search bar built in with your phone or you downloaded it? which android version you using and what phone?

Comment: @Bush Yes, I meant the google search bar built-in. The phone is Nexus 4 Android version 4.2.2

Comment: What would you like to happen, when the app is selected from the google search bar?

Comment: @DavidWasser I want the app to behave the same way, as it does when it is re-launched from the launcher. That is, restore the activity that the user had in front when he minimized it, along with the back stack order

Comment: OK, see my answer. Should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Google search bar and then select your app, it launches the root activity (in your case `ActivityA`). This is different from what the launcher does when it launches your application (if the application is already running it just brings the existing task to the foreground). To simulate this behaviour in your app you can add the following code to `ActivityA.onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
    // If we are not the root of this task, it means that this activity has been launched
    //  by another mechanism (ie: Google Search)
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        // This isn't the root of this task, so just go away quietly and drop the user
        //  into the application wherever he left it
        finish();
        return;
    }
    // ...the rest of your onCreate() goes here...
}
```

Comment: I am accepting this because this concept worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From google developer site:

> android:windowSoftInputMode How the main window of the activity
>   interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard. The
>   setting for this attribute affects two things:  The state of the soft
>   keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes
>   the focus of user attention. The adjustment made to the activity's
>   main window — whether it is resized smaller to make room for the soft
>   keyboard or whether its contents pan to make the current focus visible
>   when part of the window is covered by the soft keyboard.
>
> The setting must be one of the values listed in the following table,
>   or a combination of one "state..." value plus one "adjust..." value.
>   Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values,
>   for example — has undefined results. Individual values are separated
>   by a vertical bar (|).

In the manifest you gave 2 adjust arguments in the same time which may cause to undefined result.
Give it a try

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed it to mean only one thing as the android dev guide says. However, it has not fixed my original issue.

Comment: Well it might be depends on how google implemented their widget to behave. It could be that they search for a package with a name similar to the text you entered and then find the "launcher activity" for that package which is ActivityA and that is why ActivityA is launched.